# Center element in Bootstrap row with two elements at each side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap 3.0 and I need one row with three elements. I want one fixed at the center and other two at the left and right sides. The following code shows what I have. This works, but it makes three rows.

```
 <div class="row-centered">
  <span class="text-left">text</span>
  <div class="center-block" style="width:200px;background-color:#ccc;">...</div>
  <div class="text-right">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<div class="row">` and `<div class="col-sm-4">` (where "col-sm-4" is interchangable with classes like "col-sm-3", "col-md-4", etc.) to put elements in-line on the same row - [here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yvxqjdo/).

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">text</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="background-color:#ccc;">...</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a tradition row and take advantage of the Bootstrap Grid. Static widths are a bad idea but if you told me specifically what width you are looking to achieve we can better suit it with a column size.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 text-left">text</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 text-center" style="background-color:#CCC;">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 text-right">text</div>
</div>
```